# Django NOT NULL constraint failed: BekanSite_project.owner_id

Tags: django

I have this problem:::

IntegrityError at /addproject/
NOT NULL constraint failed: BekanSite_project.owner_id. I do not know how I can fix this problem.

This is my model ::

```
from django.db import models
from django import forms
from django.contrib.auth.models import User
from django.core.validators import URLValidator

class Project(models.Model):
    project_name = models.CharField(verbose_name='Имя 
        проекта',max_length=200, default='')
    project_cost = models.IntegerField(verbose_name='Сумма 
        инвестиции',default='')
    investor = models.IntegerField(verbose_name='Долья 
        инвестерa',default='')
    email = models.EmailField(verbose_name='Почта',max_length=50, 
        default='')..other fields

    owner = models.ForeignKey(User)

    def __str__(self):
        return self.owner
```

views.py

```
@login_required
def addproject(request):
    if request.POST:
        form = ProjectForm(request.POST, request.FILES)
        if form.is_valid():
            form.owner = request.user
            addproject = form.save()"<<<<where it fails"
            addproject.save()
            return HttpResponseRedirect(reverse('accounts:profile'))
    else:
        form = ProjectForm()
    return render(request, 'BekanSite/addproject.html', 
        {'form':form,'username':auth.get_user(request).username})
```

forms.py

```
from django.db import models
from django import forms
from .models import Project
from django.contrib.auth.forms import UserCreationForm
from django.contrib.auth.models import User
from PIL import Image
class ProjectForm(forms.ModelForm):
   class Meta:
        model = Project
        fields = ['project_name','project_cost',...(other fields),]
```

I think it is somehow related to ForeignKey. Please help. Thanks beforehand.

Answer (score 0):

You might want to attach the user before you check form is valid:

```
 if request.POST:
    form = ProjectForm(request.POST, request.FILES)
    form.owner = request.user
    if form.is_valid():
        addproject = form.save()"<<<<where it fails"
        addproject.save()
        return HttpResponseRedirect(reverse('accounts:profile'))
```

And you dont have to call addproject.save() since form.save() does that already.

Comment: my code ::: `
@login_required
def addproject(request):
    if request.POST:
        form = ProjectForm(request.POST, request.FILES)
        form.owner = request.user
        if form.is_valid():
            addproject = form.save()
            return HttpResponseRedirect(reverse('accounts:profile'))
    else:
        form = ProjectForm()
    return render(request, 'BekanSite/addproject.html', {'form':form,'username':auth.get_user(request).username})`unfortunately it does not work. could you please suggest me other ways to solve this problem.

Comment: Or maybe alter the request.POST dictionary before passing it to the form like this: request.POST['owner']  = request.user. Maybe that will work.

Answer (score 0):

I have solved it. I don't know how it works, but I just added commit=False `addproject = form.save(commit=False)`. I found it in the book "python-crash-course-a-hands-on-eric-matthes ". now it works.Also Thank you RajKris for your effort to solve this problem.Good luck.